# How to make all threads sleep - iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, nsthread

-> I am making an iphone application
-> I have a scenario where I am running number of threads in background.

-> Now suppose on main thread I receive an event and have to execute some action in a new background thread.

->But when I perform some action on the new background thread at that time my all other threads should pause/sleep till the action is completed.

-> Once the action is over all other threads should resume their operation.

I will be exploring more on this, but if any one has idea please provide some input.

Thanks

Comment: You're Correct, I have removed my answer, have you consider using Native C threads, or have you thought about a Shared Object between all thread let's say like a flag, when you set this Objet to a Current Flag all Working Threads hold till another set for this object? i used to do this Mechanism back in C#

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you want to do? What are the background threads doing? Why do they need to pause? There may be an easier solution than any suggested so far.

Answer (score 0):

Usually signalling can be done using pthread conditions,using mutex for synchronizing, Like so:

Create Mutex and Condition Variables:

```
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
```

Thread 1: Wait for the Signal:

```
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
```

Thread 2 : Signal the  thread waiting for condition:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```